# Use Angular fontawesome icon in input placeholder text

Tags: angular, font-awesome, placeholder, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I'm using official [Font Awesome Angular](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular) components in Angular 6 application.
 But I can't find way to add a search icon as placeholder to an input element except adding fontawesome fonts additionally to my app, that is not desirable.

```
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="&#xf002; Search" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I come up with such workaround:
instead of

```
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="&#xf002; Search" />
  </div>
```

I add placeholder in adjacent block

```
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-box-input" type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText"/>
    <div class="search-box-placeholder-wrapper">
      <fa-icon [icon]="faSearch" class="search-box-placeholder"></fa-icon>
      <span>&nbsp;Search</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and added additional css styles

```
.search-box {   
   position: relative;

  &-placeholder-wrapper {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 8px;  
   }

  &-input:focus + .search-box-placeholder-wrapper {
    display: none;  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install official [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css)

`npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free -s`

Import font-awesome to your styles.css

`@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';`

Now you can use font-awesome normal way and search icons from the official site.

Comment: Thanks @Anjana Thrishakya but I was looking for a way to use current package with svg icons